# Hedging delta when gamma is positive

Tags: options, option-strategies

If I have an aggregate position with a positive gamma, should I still be delta neutral? I feel like I'm giving up the positive benefits of being gamma positive because I'm killing my delta constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Delta neutral does not imply gamma neutral, so you still get gamma benefits. Looking at the Black Scholes equation, if you remove delta and hit your assumptions, your gamma gains will be offset by theta losses. If a delta hedge removes those gamma gains, then you’d just be losing on Theta, and your expected return would be negative!